# Probability of printing without a skip.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, geometric-series

The old printer in the computer room skips, on average, 1 character in 25 (i.e., the
chance of skipping any particular character is 1/25).

First part :

Determine the probability that a line of 45 characters is printed without a skip.

for the first part I thought that the probability of printing without a skip is 1-1/25, for the 45 characters : (24/25)^45 but it confuses me, I think I need to solve it with geometric series but not sure

Second part:
Determine the probability that at least one character is skipped in the first 12.

For the second part 1- probability (without a skip in the first 12)

1- (24/25)^12

Really unsure about this problem, can someone help me?

Comment: You look on the right track. I don't see a geometric series approach to these particular problems. They can however sometimes come up but I think usually when finding expected values rather than probabilities.

Comment: Both of your answers look correct to me. Why do you think that you need a geometric series?

Comment: in reference to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960997/typing-probability @Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem only gives the average probability, you are supposed to
assume the Poisson distribution according to which
\begin{equation*}
P(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda }\lambda ^{x}}{x!}\text{, where }\lambda \text{ is
the average number of events.}
\end{equation*}

Determine the probability that a line of 45 characters is printed without a skip: Since $1$ error occurs on average for $25$
characters,
\begin{equation*}
\lambda =45/25=1.8\text{ skips per }45\text{ characters on average.}
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
P(x=0)=\frac{e^{-1.8}\times (1.8)^{0}}{0!}=e^{-1.8}\approx 0.16530\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Determine the probability that at least one character is
skipped in the first $12$: This time
\begin{equation*}
\lambda =12/25=0.48\text{ skips per }12\text{ characters on average.}
\end{equation*}
Note that,
\begin{equation*}
P(x=0)=\frac{e^{-0.48}\times (1.8)^{0}}{0!}=e^{-0.48}
\end{equation*}
and we have
\begin{equation*}
P(x\geq 1)=1-P(x=0)=1-e^{-0.48}\approx 0.38122\text{.}
\end{equation*}
All the Best.

Comment: What is the basis for your assumption that the OP (i.e. original poster) is supposed to employ the Poisson Distribution?  The OP stated closed form answers to the two parts of the question as $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{24}{25}\right]^{(45)}~$ and $~\displaystyle 1 - \left[\frac{24}{25}\right]^{(12)}.$  I see nothing wrong with these closed form expressions, as is.  Why is consideration of Poisson Distribution required here?

Comment: @user2661923  If the question gave the exact probability, recourse to Binomial distribution would be appropriate. As I spelled out, the given probability is just an average one. The Poisson distribution makes three assumptions and refers to the limiting Binomial distribution.

Comment: @user2661923 These assumptions are as follows:  (1) The probability of the occurrence of an event is constant for all subintervals.  (2) There can be no more than one occurrence in each subinterval. (3) Occurrences are independent; that is an occurrence in one interval does not affect the probability of an occurrence in another interval.

Comment: Because of the nature of the questions, where what is being asked is (in effect) the probability of **zero** successes, Binomial Distribution (or any type of alternatively assumed Distribution method) is not needed here.

Comment: @user2661923 I strongly recommend that you look at the Poisson distribution. The keyword is "on average." In the binomial distribution, the probabilities need to be precise.